# NGINX BoringSSl HTTP3 ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04, quic, http3

An *ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED* error occurs in Google Chrome v.120 while trying to leverage HTTP/3 via Nginx 1.25.3 + BoringSSL. No errors, neither debug messages are found in logs while nginx-debug is on, http2 works well with this config and https://cloudflare-quic.com/ says HTTP/3 can be used by the browser.

*/etc/nginx/nginx.conf*:

```
user  www-data;
worker_processes  1;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile       on;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    tcp_nodelay    on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    

    ##
    # Access/Error Log Settings
    ##

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # SSL Configuration
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


    ##
    # FastCGI Cache Settings
    ##

    fastcgi_cache_path /etc/nginx-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=phpcache:100m inactive=60m;
    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
    fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

*/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/website.conf*:

```
server {
  server_name website.site;

  root /var/www/website/public_html/develop;
  index index.html;

  listen 443 quic reuseport;
  listen 443 ssl;

  http2 on;
  http3 on;

  quic_retry on;
  ssl_early_data on;

  add_header alt-svc 'h3=":443"; quic=":443"; ma=2592000;';

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;  

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/website.site.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/website.site-key.pem;
}
```

**UPD:** Another interesting behavior I noticed is that the connection is redirected to another available nginx vhost (looks like the listen is ignored if quiche service is used)

**My Solution:** The problem turned to be that Google Chrome does not switch to HTTP/3 protocol if certificate is not publicly trusted (the solution was found [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/proto-quic/c/aoyy_Y2ecrI/m/R-Mdl9noBAAJ?pli=1)). Nevertheless, possible causes described here help to troubleshoot other errors

Comment: "connection refused" means the connection is not reaching your nginx at all, which is why nginx doesn't and can't log anything about it. It's odd this should happen if http/2 (or even http/1.1+TLS) connections work from the same client (software _and_ network location) to the same server, but that's still where you need to start looking. BTW `"quic"` is neither a valid service (which you didn't write anyway) nor a valid parameter, and your `"v"` value uses invalid quotation marks -- only ASCII `"` is correct.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, thanks for comment. After CURLing it, the log showed the request is going to the 127.0.0.1:443 address, and the error is shown right after this. Can something be there that prevents a request from being sent to Nginx?
P.S. Edited the config: removed the `v` value from the alt-svc header as HTTP/3 already works without it, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: So the nginx is on the _same_ machine as the curl (or vice versa)? If so it _might_ be ufw/iptables/nftables -- but that should be the same for http3 as http2! Or, if a virtual machine or container is involved, that may not qualify as 'same' machine; specifically, using 127.0.0.1 may or may not reach it, depending on a number of details. (Networking was simpler when machines were real machines.)

Comment: I'm using curl together with the nginx on the same machine without any container or virtual machine involved. ufw is disabled and iptables has no special rules applied. Another interesting behavior I noticed is that the connection is redirected to another available nginx vhost (looks like the listen is ignored if quiche service is used)

Comment: FUDGE! I set up a test of this and once I looked at it it's obvious. **QUIC is UDP.** If you _only_ `listen 443 quic` nginx is 'listening' only on UDP 443 not TCP 443. (Technically UDP is connectionless and waits to receive rather than listening, but close enough.) If I use `curl -k --http3-only https://127.0.0.1` it does work, but curl's default _or_ a browser _first_ tries TCP+TLS+http connection and if the response has alt-svc browser then upgrades -- but here TCP is refused because nginx isn't listening. Eric is right, you need at least `listen 443 ssl`.

Comment: Yes, I've added the listen (updated the question code), but there are no changes except from http2 now is listening permanently (no protocol switching noticed after several refreshes). I've also tried to play with different Alt-Svc header records, containing various h3 standards/ma time. Nevertheless, Google Fonts is used in the project that is delivered by the http/3 connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web browser first establishes a http/1 or a http/2 connection.
So you need to keep 2 listen directives.
You should uncomment:

```
    # listen 443 ssl http2;
```

and replace by:

```
    listen 443 ssl;
    http2 on;
```

as http2 is not accepted anymore in the listen directive. It is a new directive disabled by default, see https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_v2_module.html#http2

```
Syntax: http2 on | off;
Default:    
http2 off;
Context:    http, server
This directive appeared in version 1.25.1.
```

and https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen

```
"The parameter is deprecated, the http2 directive should be used instead."
```

See also this working example at https://nginx.org/en/docs/quic.html#example

```
http {
    log_format quic '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http3"';

    access_log logs/access.log quic;

    server {
        # for better compatibility it's recommended
        # to use the same port for quic and https
        listen 8443 quic reuseport;
        listen 8443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate     certs/example.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key certs/example.com.key;

        location / {
            # required for browsers to direct them to quic port
            add_header Alt-Svc 'h3=":8443"; ma=86400';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've already thought about this thing, but everything that happened was the browser was establishing the http/2 connection even after numerous page refresh trials. This is why the `listen http2 ssl;` line is commented on for now.

Comment: Using more_set_headers directive instead of add_header allows to display the header as early as the first answer of Nginx, ex:  `more_set_headers 'Alt-Svc: h3=":443';`  Also, the web browser prefers to use the cache so it is useful to clear the cache.  As I mentionned earlier, you have to uncomment the listen ssl directive to initiate a transaction.

Comment: Can you, please, provide me with some details on how to add this directive to nginx? I've found that installing the nginx-extras can provide it but while `apt install nginx-extras`, the previous nginx 1.25 with the boringSSL setup is removed and changed with the default version of 1.18. Should something be added to the nginx `make` command flags?

Comment: Before the make command, I add a flag like `--add-module=../headers-more-nginx-module-0.37` to the configure command, after getting the latest sources from https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module/tags, see also https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/headers_more/

Answer (score 0):

I found an example config and you need some more things in the vhost

```
server{
    listen 443 http3 quic reuseport;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    quic_retry on;
    ssl_early_data on;

    http3_max_field_size 5000;
    http3_max_table_capacity 50;
    http3_max_blocked_streams 30;
    http3_max_concurrent_pushes 30;
    http3_push 10;
    http3_push_preload on;

    add_header alt-svc '$quic=":443"; ma=3600';
index index.html index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com

    root /var/www/yourdomain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; 
}
server{
    if ($host = http3.codefaq.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;

    server_name yourdomain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

See here https://codefaq.org/server/how-to-install-http-3-quic-on-nginx-server-for-ubuntu/#adding-boringssl-and-http3

Comment: Yes, I've tried this config before, but it turned to show that 'http3_max_field_size' is not a valid parameter and what is more, the http3 listen service is not defined